# Split strings into tokens with delimiter (/ and -) in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string, Line = "3QQT38/28-12/AA";
How can i split it if i dont know my delimiter sequence. 
Note : / and - can come in any sequence.

Output for above string should be 4 substrings
3QQT38
28
12
AA

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Give *multiple* examples of how your delimiters can "come in any sequence". [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49344938/edit) to do so, including whatever code you've tried thus far.

Comment: It can be "3QQT38/28-12/AA" OR "3QQ-28/A-S" OR "3QQ/23"

Comment: [Code snippet](http://cpp.sh/94733)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable time & suggestions!